# How to refer to specific jquery ui tabs by their index such as in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

One thought is that perhaps I should create an array and just .each() all of the tabs to create references in the manner I would like but it seems there is probably already a way to do this I just may not be aware of the scope or syntax.

For instance I have $tabs.tabs() and I want to change the AJAX URL and title of a given index  such as:

```
for (var x = index; x < (tab_counter - 1); x++) {  
    $tabs.tabs(x).text(!!$tabs.tabs(x + 1).text() ? $tabs.tabs(x + 1).text() : "Deleted");
    //is there a syntax to refer to tabs in this manner?
}
```

$tabs has been initialized as
`var $tabs = $("#pages").tabs( ...`

Assume that tab_counter is kept up to date (it is incremented and decremented in the add and remove events) - If I try as suggested something like 
`for (var x = 0; x < (tab_counter - 1); x++) { 
    console.log($tabs.tabs.eq(x).text() + " @ index " + x);
  
  }`
 In order to for example loop through all of the tabs titles. Is there something I am missing here in the syntax? eq() seems to be the right solution, but I suspect I am not using it right.

### Solution

```
$tabis = $('#pages ul li a');

for (var x = 0; x < tab_counter; x++) {  
  console.log($tabis.eq(x).text() + " at " + x);
}

/* Prints the text label of each tab within the selected list of tabs. */
```

Thank you for your help dbaseman thats exactly what I was looking for. And I learned in the process so I am greatful for that

Comment: What do you have in your `$tabs` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *[eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)* perhaps?

```
$tabs.eq(x).text( ... )
```

Comment: If $tabs is defined as `var $tabs = $("#pages").tabs( ...` and I tried `$tabs.tabs.eq(x).text` and `$tabs.eq(x).text()` to no avail, how should I correctly reference this?

Comment: @MichaelAnthony I was assuming $tabs was an array of the objects to enumerate (perhaps incorrect).  For my answer to work, you'd have to set $tabs = $("selector that selects all tabs").

Comment: The ID of the tabs container is #pages but selecting using that did not work, so I tried more specifically `'#pages ul'` but no success. I don't think I am understanding how to return the proper set of elements. I am learning more though as I experiment with it

Answer (score 0):

The tabs are all given consistently-named `id` attributes you could select.

Comment: That is true I may go that route after all - I still would like to for the sake of learning know how to access the elements in this manner though, because I think this is a piece of the JS puzzle I have not quite solved for myself.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make you own function that returns objects from the IDs of each tab:

```
$tabs.tabs = function (index) {
        return $("#tab" + index);
}
```

This assumes you tabs have IDs of "tab0", "tab1", etc., but it could work with any IDs.